# How to use axios to send request to a route that requires parameter?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I am trying to use axios to make a request to a route:

app.get("/mentorRequestAccept/:userId", userController.mentorRequestApprove);

which takes in a userId parameter. However, this is not working and I believe that I am not using using axios specifically the line:  axios.get("/api/mentorRequestAccept?userId=", id);. Can someone verify that this is the correct syntax as I am not very familiar with it.

```
      approveUser(id){
        console.log("APPROVE BUTTON CLICKED", id);
        axios.get("/api/mentorRequestAccept?userId=", id);
      }

      render() {
        console.log("USERS", this.state.users);``
        return (
          <div className="mentorRequest">
            {this.state.users.map((user) => 
            <div>
                {user.username}
                <button onClick={() => this.approveUser(user._id)}>Approve</button>
                <button onClick={() => this.rejectUser(user._id)}>Reject</button>
            </div>)}
          </div>
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is string format:

```
axios.get(`/api/mentorRequestAccept/${id}`)
```

Or simple string concatination:

```
axios.get('/api/mentorRequestAccept/' + id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
approveUser(id){
        console.log("APPROVE BUTTON CLICKED", id);
        axios.get(`/api/mentorRequestAccept/${id}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `params` to config as a second parameter of `axis.get` function:

```
axios.get('/api/mentorRequestAccept/', {
  params: { id },
};
```